# Filtrar datos de un df

Tags: python, pandas

| state | production | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| alabama | 928000 | 1995 |
| arizona | 52000 | 2000 |
| florida | 84900 | 2021 |
| georgia | 261000 | 1995 |
| hawai | 15000 | 2021 |

Quiero filtrar en el año 2021 que estado tuvo la mayor producción, probe con *loc* (el df se llama "miel")

```
miel.loc[(miel.year==2021) & (miel.production.max())]
```

Creo que el problema esta en la segunda parte del código pero no se como resolverlo.

También pensé en agruparlos con *group by* pero no se como especificar el año 2021 y si esta bien escrito el código para predecir el máximo.

```
miel.groupby(year).production.max()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtra los datos según la condición y obtiene el registro con la mayor producción asi:

```
max_production = miel.loc[(miel['year']==2021), 'production'].max()
result = miel.loc[miel['production']==max_production]
```

De tu código, si, la segunda parte deberías de igualar:

```
registro = miel.loc[(miel.year==2021) & (miel.production == miel.production.max())]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!